# String filter for YAML array?

Tags: arrays, yaml, jekyll

Is there a way in Jekyll to add a string filter for `{{ data[1] }}` in this YAML hash, so that the comma after "amet" doesn't break the array?

```
- project:
  -
    name: Name
    main:
      - image: image.png, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit., category, Main Category, placeholdertext
```

Edit: @marcanuy asked how `data[1]` is defined. It's the index location in a for loop, and I'm using it for an alt tag: `alt="{{ data[1] | strip }}"`, so:

```
{% for main in project.main %}

    {% assign main = site.data.catalog[0].project[0].main[0] %}
    {% assign data = main.image|split:"," %}
```

Comment: How is data[1] defined?

Comment: @marcanuy I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can simplify you catalog file structure.

#### _data/catalog.yml

Contains all projets in an array :

```
-
  name: Name1
  main:
    image:
      url: image1.png
      alt: 1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      category: 1Main Category
      placeholderText: 1placeholdertext
-
  name: Name2
  main:
    image:
      url: image2.png
      alt: 2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      category: 2Main Category
      placeholderText: 2placeholdertext
```

Now, you can get stuff with :

```
{% for project in site.data.catalog  %}
  {% assign mainImg = project.main.image %}
    <img src="{{ site.base }}{{ maybe.img.path.from.config }}{{ mainImg.url }}" alt="{{ mainImg.alt }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This wound up being the best solution in the end! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answers: create a new array with the first item removed (the name of the image) and the join the rest of the elements with a comma to restore the original text:

```
Image name: {{ data |first | strip }}
{% assign text = data | shift %}
Image text: {{ text | join: "," }}
```

Output:

```
Image name: image.png

Image text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit., category, Main Category, placeholdertext
```